# Creating Modeless div in mvc3 view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

My motive is to create a progress image while postbacking to the server in mvc3 view. when ever process is running the progress image with background div should popup. the popup should not allow to access controls on the page. for example i have dropdown in my view, when i post back back progess image should come and i should not allow to click on dropdown.

i have tried many ways all are working if it is not postbacking but while postback is happending i am able to click on actual page controls. but i should not allow to click. any help?

the code which i tried is...

```
<style type="text/css">
.modal
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    z-index: 99;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.loading
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10pt;
    border: 5px solid #67CFF5;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: White;
    z-index: 999;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowProgress() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var modal = $('<div />');
        modal.addClass("modal");
        $('body').append(modal);
        var loading = $(".loading");
        loading.show();
        var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
        var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
        loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
    }, 200);
}
$('form').live("submit", function () {
    ShowProgress();
});
```

```
<div class="loading" align="center">
Loading. Please wait.<br />
<br />
<img src="loader.gif" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use jquery UI dialog box for it and set opacity.
you can find some examples here
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Comment: i tried this. this is working for clientside(javascript) validation. but while postbacking, i am opening the popup, and letting process go but i am able to click background. actually i should not allow to click background. this is the issue here.

Comment: Firstly I am guessing that you are doing ajax post. not a full page post back. If you are doing a full page post back then you can not get what you are looking for.